# What's the exact difference between gdb and actual OS environment for multiprocess?

Tags: linux, multithreading, gdb, scheduled-tasks

I've been debugging multi-process job. Create multiple threads at program initialization. I found while I'm using gdb for debug, the threads can all be set up successfully, but when I execute the program directly in linux environment, it stucks after part of the threads being created. I'm thinking it must be some schedule problem between thread sleep and wakeup but haven't figure that out yet..

And although gdb can create the threads successfully, it quits with an unexpected segmentation fault in a glibc function after thread killed itself:
`res_thread_freeres () at res_init.c:642
642   if (_res.nscount == 0)`
 
which is also wierd because I can check the value of _res.nscount, it didn't overflow definately.

So.. Does anybody have a clue about the execution difference between an actual os and gdb debug environment? Thanks!

Update: 
I've located the problem to pthread being set to SCHED_FIFO, after I removed this, it works fine. But I'm still not aware of why the program works fine in gdb environment.. Actually the thread state of the program got changed the moment it is attached to gdb.

Comment: If your program has a race condition it is likely to exhibit timing-dependent behaviour. It is hard to tell anything more specific. Try introducing random sleeps in key places and see if behaviour changes; if it does it is almost certainly a race condition or perhaps some other kind of synchronisation error.

Comment: thanks @n.m.  I find this is because one of the FIFO thread never sleeps that may cause the hung, since the program works fine once I force the thread to sleep. But weird thing is that I've already bind each thread to different cpu, which I think should not cause the race condition..

Comment: Race conditions are caused by unsynchronised access to shared resources, they occur in all CPU configurations.